# Jquery UI autocomplete from two data sources in Asp.net MVC5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am working on a ASP.net MVC5 (C#) web application am trying to show autocomplete data from two different tables (one is device table and other one is news table) in a div in single textbox like [phonearena.com](http://www.phonearena.com) is showing, when you input a query they show all the phones and tablets containing that query and also the news and reviews.
[image]

right now I am able to autocomplete data from one datasource like this.

```
$(function () {
function log(message) { }

$("#search_input").autocomplete({
    source: "/Search/?term",
    minLength: 1,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#mobile").val(ui.item.title);
        $("#mobile-query").val(ui.item.query);
        return false;
    }
})
.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
    .append("<a href='/" + item.query + "'>" + item.title + "</a>")
    .appendTo(ul);
};
```

});

I want to show devices and news lists in a div. Please see on the site I mentioned about and write any famous phone, and drop down div will pop out with records. Can you guys please help me figuring this out. Thanks

**Tables Structure**

**Device Table**

**Device_Id**-----**Device_Name**-----**Device_Query**

1-----------------iPhone 6---------------iphone_6

2-----------------Galaxy S6--------------galaxy-s6

3-----------------Lumia 990--------------lumia_990

**News Table**

**News_id**------**News_Title**---------------**News_Query**----------------**Device_Id**

1-----------iPhone 6 Review---------------iphone-6-review----------------------1

2-----------iPhone 6 Pros & Cons----------iphone-6-pros-cons----------------1

3-----------Lumia 990 Camera Review-------lumia-990-camera-review-----3

Comment: can you provide table structure of both your tables.

Comment: @Nitin: I just update question with a table structure. Thanks

Comment: but I just wanna show news, according to the query. I mean the Titles which contains the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this you can create two queries with same column names and union it like :

```
select device_name as title, device_query as query, 'device' as q_type from device_table // add your where clause here

union 

select news_title as title, news_query as query, 'news' as q_type from news_table // add your where clause here
```

and in autocomplete

```
.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {

if(item.q_type == "device")
{
// add your device type html
}
else
{
 // add your news type html
}
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I was just looking for a head start. This helped a lot. :)